# Spark JPMML import Issue

Tags: apache-spark, pmml

Am trying to import a PMML Model file, generated in R to Spark Context and use it to predict the scores. This is the code used in Spark.

```
JavaRDD<String> scoreData = data.map(new Function<String, String>() {

    @Override
    public String call(String line) throws Exception {
        String[] row = line.split(",");
        PMML pmml;
        Evaluator evaluator;
        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());
        FSDataInputStream inStr = fs.open(new Path("PATH_TO_PMML_FILE"));
        Source transformedSource = ImportFilter.apply(new InputSource(inStr));
        pmml = JAXBUtil.unmarshalPMML(transformedSource);
        System.out.println(pmml.getModels().get(0).getModelName());
        ModelEvaluatorFactory modelEvaluatorFactory = ModelEvaluatorFactory.newInstance();
        ModelEvaluator<?> modelEvaluator = modelEvaluatorFactory.newModelManager(pmml);
        System.out.println(modelEvaluator.getSummary());
        evaluator = (Evaluator) modelEvaluator;

        List<FieldName> activeFields = evaluator.getActiveFields();
        double[] features = new double[row.length - 2]; // row - {contact_id,label}  
        StringBuilder strBld = new StringBuilder();
        Map<FieldName, FieldValue> arguments = new LinkedHashMap<FieldName, FieldValue>();
        strBld.append(row[0]);
        for (int i = 3; i <= row.length - 1; i++) {
            //from f1 - f16
            FieldValue activeValue = evaluator.prepare(activeFields.get(i - 3), Double.parseDouble(row[i]));
            arguments.put(activeFields.get(i - 3), activeValue);
        }
    }
```

The code worked fine when run in core Java environment(without Spark context), but when running the above code I get the following exception

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Range.closed(Ljava/lang/Comparable;Ljava/lang/Comparable;)Lcom/google/common/collect/Range;
at org.jpmml.evaluator.Classification$Type.<clinit>(Classification.java:278)
at org.jpmml.evaluator.ProbabilityDistribution.<init>(ProbabilityDistribution.java:26)
at org.jpmml.evaluator.GeneralRegressionModelEvaluator.evaluateClassification(GeneralRegressionModelEvaluator.java:333)
at org.jpmml.evaluator.GeneralRegressionModelEvaluator.evaluate(GeneralRegressionModelEvaluator.java:107)
at org.jpmml.evaluator.ModelEvaluator.evaluate(ModelEvaluator.java:266)
at org.zcoe.spark.pmml.PMMLSpark_2$1.call(PMMLSpark_2.java:146)
at org.zcoe.spark.pmml.PMMLSpark_2$1.call(PMMLSpark_2.java:1)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD$$anonfun$toScalaFunction$1.apply(JavaPairRDD.scala:999)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1157)
at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1157)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$17.apply(RDD.scala:813)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$17.apply(RDD.scala:813)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1503)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1503)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:61)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:203)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The issue seems to be with the compatibility of Guvava Jar file which is required to run the code.
I removed all the Jars containing the com.google.common.collect.Range Class from Spark's class path, but still the same issue persists.

The Spark Job details are below,

spark-submit --jars ./lib/pmml-evaluator-1.2.0.jar,./lib/pmml-model-1.2.2.jar,./lib/pmml-manager-1.1.20.jar,./lib/pmml-schema-1.2.2.jar,./lib/guava-15.0.jar --class

[Stage 0:>                                                                                                     (0 + 2) / 2]15/06/26 14:39:15 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 1 on hslave2: remote Akka client disassociated
15/06/26 14:39:15 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on hslave1: remote Akka client disassociated
[Stage 0:>                                                                                                     (0 + 2) / 2]15/06/26 14:39:33 ERROR YarnScheduler: Lost executor 4 on hslave1: remote Akka client disassociated
15/06/26 14:39:33 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, hslave1): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 4 lost)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1203)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1192)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1191)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:693)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1393)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1354)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Please let me know if any mistakes I have done.

Comment: I am trying to do the exactly the same thing but want to create the model once and pass it inside `map{}`, have you tried that approach for better performance? https://www.mail-archive.com/user@spark.apache.org/msg42171.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let both Spark and JPMML have their own version of Guava libraries. It is not a good idea to modify Spark base installation when you can achieve your goal by simply re-working the packaging of your Spark application.

If you move your Spark application to Apache Maven, then it is possible to use the [relocation feature of the Maven Shade Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) to move JPMML's version of Guava library to another package such as `org.jpmml.com.google`. The [example application of the JPMML-Cascading project](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-cascading/blob/master/pmml-cascading-example/pom.xml) does this trick.

Also, the upside of moving to Apache Maven is that your Spark application will be available as an uber-JAR file, which greatly simplifies its deployment. For example, at the moment you are specifying `pmml-manager-1.1.20.jar` on your command line, which is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am very new to Maven, can you please provide bit of insights on how to do this thing.

Comment: To get started, take the reference JPMML-Cascading POM file and replace Cascading dependencies with Spark dependencies. Then put your application source to `src/main/java` directory and build using `mvn clean install`.

Comment: Its working with the suggestion you gave @user1808924. Thanks a lot for the help